# Scientific notation in d3.js axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to plot some extremely small values with d3.js. Is there a direct way to visualise the tick labels in scientific (exponential) notation?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

</style>
<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->     
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// parse the date / time
var data = [[0.3, 5e-300],[0.1, 3e-300],[0.7, 4e-300],[0.2, 7e-300],[0.6, 2.5e-300],[0.9, 4.2e-300]]

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]).domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[0]; })]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]).domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[1]; })]);


// append the svg obgect to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d,i) { return x(d[0]); } )
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d[1]); } )
      .attr("r", 8);

// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
    .tickFormat(d3.formatPrefix(".1s", 1e-300)));;


</script>
</body>
```

Here's an example created with in matplotlib. I would like to achieve the same thing with regard to y-axis notation

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution with [`d3.format`](https://github.com/d3/d3-format#format):

```
svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".1e")));
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// parse the date / time
var data = [[0.3, 5e-300],[0.1, 3e-300],[0.7, 4e-300],[0.2, 7e-300],[0.6, 2.5e-300],[0.9, 4.2e-300]]

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]).domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[0]; })]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]).domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[1]; })]);


// append the svg obgect to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d,i) { return x(d[0]); } )
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d[1]); } )
      .attr("r", 8);

// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".1e")));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for